# Count number of columns in SQL (Impala)

Tags: sql, sql-server, impala

I am trying to count the number of columns in a table in Impala.

My following code works in Microsoft SQL Server but giving me error in Impala. any thoughts?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database_name'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Error from impala:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: ...' from
>   information_schema.COLUMNS  ^ Encountered: COLUMNS Expected: DEFAULT,
>   IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: I'm not familiar with Impala, but I'm guessing it treats `COLUMNS` as a context-insensitive keyword, in which case try escaping it. I believe Impala uses backticks to escape reserved words like MySQL does, so try: `...FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.\`COLUMNS\`.`

Comment: Tried, didn't work. Got the same error.

Comment: Oh, you have a trailing comma after `COUNT(*),` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry,just updated my post and removed comma. Still giving me the same error.

Comment: Try giving the Count(*) a Column Alias

Answer (score 0):

Dai (above) is correct. Metadata names that clash with keys words (in this case "column") can be simply escaped by using backward ticks within impala.

Please see here: https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_identifiers.html